# Can't put tkinter widget inside Toplevel Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to open a toplevel widget from a button press, and generate a list within that frame from an example I found.  However, when I try to place the widget within the generated frame, I get the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't put .!treeview inside .!errorexample.!toplevel.!mclistdemo.!frame.!frame
```

I have narrowed down the problem to

self.tree.grid(**in_=f,** row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

within the _create_treeview method.  When the in_ command is removed, the widget is generated correctly in the parent window.  I suspect that the problem has something to do with my parent/self naming conventions, but I am still struggling to grasp that subject.

Most of the questions I've run across that are described similarly seem to be a matter of trying to place the widget while generating it, but that doesn't seem to be the case in this code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

class ErrorExample(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.grid()
        self.parent=parent

        self.b4=Button(
            self,
            text="Load",
            command=lambda: self.createWindow())
        self.b4.grid()

    def createWindow(self):
        self.t = Toplevel(self)
        MCListDemo(self)

class MCListDemo(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, isapp=True):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent.t)
        self.grid()
        self.isapp = isapp
        self._create_widgets()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        if self.isapp:
            self._create_demo_panel()

    def _create_demo_panel(self):
        demoPanel = Frame(self)
        demoPanel.grid()
        self._create_treeview(demoPanel)
        self._load_data()

    def _create_treeview(self, parent):
        f = ttk.Frame(parent)
        f.grid()
        self.dataCols = ('country', 'capital', 'currency')        
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.dataCols, 
                                 show = 'headings')
        self.tree.grid(in_=f, row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

start=Tk()
ErrorExample(start)
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give the treeview a parent, so it has the root window as a parent. Widgets live in a hierarchy, and widget's can't be placed in a different part of the hierarchy.

The official documentation describes it like this:

> The master for each slave must either be the slave's parent (the default) or a descendant of the slave's parent. This restriction is necessary to guarantee that the slave can be placed over any part of its master that is visible without danger of the slave being clipped by its parent.

If you want the treeview to be in `f`, the simplest way is to make `f` be the parent:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(f, ...)
self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
```